# How to add tokens in an text-area in the contact module?

Tags: 8, emails

In contact module there is an text-area of auto reply in which I want to add tokens to it. Could anyone give solution for above issue.

Answer (score 1):

That is not a supported feature right now, you would have to implement that yourself using the [token API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Utility%21Token.php/class/Token/8), e.g. through a `hook_mail_alter()`.

But there are a lot of details involved after that and you won't get a detailed answer here that you can just copy & paste. You could open a feature request for http://drupal.org/project/contact_storage

Answer (score 1):

I have not yet try Contact module.

But if that is text area and can be applied a Text format, you can add [Token filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/token_filter) module then edit the text format to Replace token with actual value.